# How to add timer with start/stop GUI in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been googeling all day, tried loads of different ways, but I can't get this code to work. I want a simple timer that run a function when you press "Start", and stops when you press "Stop".

Example:
When you press start, the function will print every second "Hello World", until you press stop.

My code with some comments so you can understand faster:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Timer
# a boolean for telling the timer to stop
stop_timer = False

mgui = Tk()

def work(var):
    # stop_timers sets to True or False with Start/Stop
    stop_timer = var
    # work_done will evaluate if timer should start or be canceled
    def work_done(var2):
        stop_timer = var2
        # if stop was pressed t.start() will be ignored
        if stop_timer == False:
            t.start()
        # if stop was pressed timer will stop
        if stop_timer == True:
            print "Stopped!"
            t.cancel()
    t = Timer(1, work, [False])
    print "Something"
    work_done(var)

mgui.geometry('450x450')
mgui.title('Test')

cmd1 = lambda: work(False)
btn = Button(mgui, text="Start", command =cmd1).place(x=50, y=50)
cmd2 = lambda: work(True)
btn2 = Button(mgui, text="Stop", command =cmd2).place(x=100, y=50)

mgui.mainloop()
```

As you can tell, I'm new to this shizzle!
Thanks, mates!

Comment: Is there anything holy about tkinter?  Or would you be very opposed to a solution in wxPython?

Comment: I am not a tkinter guy, but I guess I can help you out with PyQt. Also what is the problem with the code you have written?

Comment: Do you mean "timer" in the conventional sense, as in "a thing that counts the amount of time elapsed since starting"? Or "timer" in the `threading` sense, as in "An object representing an action that should be run only after a certain amount of time has passed"?

Comment: @wnnmaw Nothing holy about it at all! I looked around for a gui yesterday, and that came up. Please post your solution!

gravetii Oh, I missed to say what was wrong! I'll edit that in the main post. But yeah, the timer never stops.

Kevin in a threading way. It should run every second until I tell it to not do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generic timer, you can also implement one in tkinter using `after`:

```
import time
import Tkinter as tk

import threading

class MyTimer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, t):
        super(MyTimer,self).__init__()
        self.txt = t
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.txt['text'] = time.time()        


mgui = tk.Tk()
mgui.title('Test')

txt = tk.Label(mgui, text="time")
txt.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

timer = None
def cmd1():
    global timer
    timer = MyTimer(txt)
    timer.start()
def cmd2():
    global timer
    if timer:
        timer.running = False
        timer= None

btn = tk.Button(mgui, text="Start", command =cmd1)
btn.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn2 = tk.Button(mgui, text="Stop", command =cmd2)
btn2.grid(row=1,column=2)

mgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I was not clear enough. What I'm looking for is a timer that loops a function.

Comment: What do you mean with _loops a function_?

Comment: a function to be called over and over again. I managed to get it working with your code - thanks a ton!

Comment: I was about to say you that inside `MyTimer.run` you can call the function you like, I've just updated the label as a way of showing it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

By editing some in xndrme's post, I finally got it to work. Thank you!

I'll post the code here for possible future googlers.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Timer

mgui = Tk()

def cmd2():
    global t
    if t:
        t.cancel()

def looper():
    global t
    t = Timer(1, looper)
    t.start()
    print "Hello World!"

mgui.geometry('450x450')
mgui.title('Test')

btn = Button(mgui, text="Start", command =looper).place(x=50, y=50)
btn2 = Button(mgui, text="Stop", command =cmd2).place(x=100, y=50)

mgui.mainloop()
```